# VB arguments are not passed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to pass argument from VB to CMD but it is not working, it will only open me CMD window. Can any one suggest me what am I doing wrong?

```
Dim start_info As New ProcessStartInfo()

    start_info.FileName = ("cmd.exe")
    start_info.UseShellExecute = False
    start_info.Arguments = "ipconfig"

    Dim proc As New Process
    proc.StartInfo = start_info
    proc.Start()
```

Comment: Have you tried running `ipconfig` directly with this code?

Comment: Yes and it worked (in console oppend by VB)

Comment: You need to use start_info.Arguments = "/c ipconfig".  The /c option tells cmd.exe that it needs to interpret its argument as a command.  Use /k instead of /c if you need to troubleshoot an error message from a failing command.  Using cmd.exe explicitly in a case like this is really only useful if you redirect output.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the above code it is the same as calling "cmd.exe ipconfig" which simply launches the command line with argument ipconfig. If you ran that from a command line window you would see no results. You can simplify the above code:

```
start_info.FileName = ("ipconfig")
start_info.UseShellExecute = False
```